# How to plot spectrum using FFTW3/ QWT?

Tags: c++, plot, fft, fftw, qwt

I want to plot the frequency spectrum  (like they do for example in Audacity). Hence I want the frequency in Hertz on the x-axis and the amplitude  on the y-axis.
My input is a periodically sine wave with 0,7 as  amplitude and 500HZ as frequency.I use FFTW to compute the magnitude and QWT  to plot.
My problem , what parameters should I put in setSamples to get a pic on 500 HZ ? 
Any help  would be appreciated
here is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#aa51cd3fa00f2a046ca5a9889c5db2413) you must set two pointers to data that build the curve and the size (number of samples in your case).

```
void QwtPlotCurve::setSamples(const double *xData, const double *yData, int size)
```

In your case yData is the data from FFT, the xData is an array that sweep from min to max/2 frequency values of the FFT discarding the other half when the signal is a real signal:

```
curve->setSamples(signalx, magnitude, N/2);
```

this should work if I'm correct.

**EDIT**

Change also:

```
signalx[i]=i;
magnitude[i]=sqrt(reout[i]*reout[i] + imgout[i]*imgout[i]); //calculate magnitude
```

to:

```
signalx[i]=(double)(Fs * i) / (double)N;
magnitude[i]=sqrt(reout[i]*reout[i] + imgout[i]*imgout[i]) / ((double)N / 2.0);
```

to represent the frequency for magnitude[i] element in plot.

You should check also for the [nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). Sampling 500Hz sine wave at 1000Hz produce aliasing and if you plot your signal[] data (at discrete steps) you can see it.

Comment: Thanks Marco, my graph is still  empty despite the change f code

Comment: I've updated the answer hoping that this time it works properly. If not [this link](https://github.com/berndporr/comedirecord/blob/master/fftscope.cpp)  can be usefull. Sorry but I can't test Qwt/ffw3 libraries.

Comment: when I set the samplerate Fs=8000 Hz and f=1000Hz, on the graph the pic is 2000Hz, when f=500Hz, on the graph pic is 1000Hz. I have the impression pic on the graph take the double of input frequency

Comment: You're right, I have see my old C FFT code that calculate only first half (real signal). Answer updated. A question: your amplitude is correctly represented?

Comment: The amplitude is correctly represented for magnitude[i]=sqrt(reout[i]*reout[i] + imgout[i]*imgout[i]) / (double)N/2; otherwise is not correctly represented