# Which framework is necessary for plotting spectrum using FFTW3/ QWT

Tags: xcode, plot, fftw, qwt, spectrum

I finished computing fftw values and now I want to plot the magnitude. So I was reading about QWT and I found so many examples  (but  in c++).
[How to plot spectrum using FFTW3/QWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24353795/3553742)

Is it posiblie to use  QWT in Xcode? 
 I install the QWT library and I have the qwt-framework. So do I need more framework? 
And which Headers should I add?
Any idea?
Or maybe something else to plot FFTW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an QWT expert but try the QtCore.framework.
Headers, it's depend on what u really need.

> Qwt_plot_curve.h
>
> Qwt_plot.h
>
> Qwt_plot.h qapplication.h